# How can I safely reinstall Docker without removing volumes?

Tags: docker

I have an issue with my docker installation in which DNS resolution is not working within my containers. How can I safely reinstall docker on Ubuntu 16.04 without removing existing volumes?

Comment: We need more information about your current setup of Docker. How did you install docker? Official Ubuntu repositories or docker.com?

Comment: I installed the docker-ce package from the official docker repository.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turns out that when uninstalling docker using apt, the `/var/lib/docker` directory remains untouched, and the volumes will stay intact.

You can simply run `apt-get remove docker-ce` to uninstall docker without removing your volumes.

Comment: This [document](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/) has some information on that.

Answer (score 4):

Before getting so drastic, try [this reset tip](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/866#issuecomment-19218300):

```
pkill docker
iptables -t nat -F
ifconfig docker0 down
brctl delbr docker0
docker -d
```

It will force docker to recreate the bridge and reinit all the network rules

Comment: on ifconfig is says: `Command 'ifconfig' not found, but can be installed with: sudo apt install net-tools`. Do I need to install net-tools?